# My Python Selenium code is getting executed in my PC but when running it on Virtual Machine, It is not clicking on any link and showing this error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine

This is my part of code which clicks on particular element and error I'm getting is:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement
```

Code:

```
counter=0
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='burger-menu-wrap']")))
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='burger-menu-wrap']")
    element.click()
    sleep(1)
    try:
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'social-media-wrap')]//li/a")
        print(len(elements))
        for element in elements:
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element))
                element.click()
                class_name = element.get_attribute("class")
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                counter += 1
                print(f"Counter1: {counter}")
                sleep(5)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='burger-menu-wrap']")
        element.click()
        sleep(1)
        
    except:
        pass
        
except:
    print("Menu Button UnClickable")
    pass
try:
    
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'social-media-wrap')]//li/a")
    print(len(elements))
    for element in elements:
        try:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
            sleep(1)
            xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'social-media-wrap')]//li/a[" + elements.index(element) + "]"
            WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            counter += 1
            print(f"Counter2: {counter}")
            sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
except Exception as e:
    print("Button not found")
```